# Cardinal number of a set comprised of the multiplication of 2 other sets.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following question in my assignment:

Find the cardinal number of the following set:

$\{a \cdot b \mid a \in \{1, 2, 3\}, b \in \{1, 2, 3\} \}$

I am wondering if this is asking for the cross product of $a$ and $b$ (i.e. $a × b$, which would be $\{(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)\}$) or would it be the set of all possible products (i.e. $\{1,2,3,4,6,9\}$).

Can anyone help me interpret this question?

Thanks!

Comment: I would read it as the cardinality of $\{1,2,3,4,6,9\}$, i.e. $6$

Comment: I think by the single dot between the $a$ and $b$, they mean the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be interpreted as the possible products of those integers. Read in English,

$$\{a\cdot b \mid a,b \in \{1,2,3\}\}$$

could be read as "the set of all possible (distinct) products of $a,b$ where $a,b$ each can be any of $1,2,$ or $3$."

Thus in turn your enumeration $\{1,2,3,4,6,9\}$ is correct (and has cardinality $6$).

---

To look at the analogue for the other interpretation, we can define the Cartesian product of two sets $A,B$ to be

$$A \times B = \{(a,b) \mid a\in A, b\in B \}$$

Notice that the Cartesian product is based on ordered pairs, not individual products. In English, this could be read as "all possible pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a$ comes from $A$ and $b$ comes from $B$".